# Issues setting up API on Elastic Beanstalk with HTTPS requests

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

So, I've been trying for time to get the following working:

- Hosting front-end application on S3 Bucket (with HTTPS support)
- Hosting Spring Boot API with Elastic Beanstalk (with HTTPS support)
- Make requests from front-end application to API (with HTTPS support)

My current setup for EBS is, the API is sitting behind a load balancer with Route 53 directing incoming requests to the load balancer, which then sends an internal HTTP request to EBS.

It was quite painful for me to get to this point (This is all pretty new to me) and after getting this set up, I'm receiving a CORS error when trying to make a request to the API from my front-end.  I'm not seeing anything in the logs and my Spring Boot CORS is set up to accept all, so this leads me to believe that the Load Balancer is causing the CORS error.

I'm wondering if I'm on the right track at all? Could the load balancer be causing this issue?  Can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your main class below main function

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedHeaders("*");
        }
    };
}
```